# Create uniformly spaced points in a given direction

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

Suppose I have a line in 2D and in an arbitrary direction. I would like to create uniformly spaced points along this line. I thought of one way to code this but seems like it can get messy, are there any libraries in Python/Numpy that do this?

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried already and what the limitations of your method is.

Comment: But you can probably do this with numpy.linspace

Comment: @C-Math What's wrong with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64998934/3944322)? It's exactly the same you ask again now (just set `k` to a multiple of `n`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating equidistance points along the boundary of a polygon but CW/CCW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64995977/generating-equidistance-points-along-the-boundary-of-a-polygon-but-cw-ccw)

Comment: You need to explain the problem in better shape so we can help better. Maybe an example of your input (and how you store the line) as well as desired output would help clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that there is no any library function to generate your list of points
and you have to generate it with your own code.

Assume that your line is defined by 2 following points (*x* and *y* coordinates):

```
p0 = np.array([1.0, 1.0])
p1 = np.array([3.0, 2.0])
```

Assume also the number of "additional" points to create as:

```
n = 10
```

Then, to create a list of points (a *Numpy* array of shape *n + 2, 2*),
compute the difference between these points:

```
dlt = p1 - p0
```

and run:

```
result = np.vstack([ p0 + i * dlt for i in range(n + 2) ])
```

The result is:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  2.],
       [ 5.,  3.],
       [ 7.,  4.],
       [ 9.,  5.],
       [11.,  6.],
       [13.,  7.],
       [15.,  8.],
       [17.,  9.],
       [19., 10.],
       [21., 11.],
       [23., 12.]])
```

so that first 2 points are *p0* and *p1* and other points are located
further on the same line, in equal steps of size *dlt*.

## Edit

To generate a list of *n* points **between** 2 points (*p0* and *p1*),
including both these terminal points, you can run:

```
result = np.vstack([np.linspace(p0[0], p1[0], n), np.linspace(p0[1], p1[1], n)]).T
```

But if you have a **polygon** then, for each side you should define the number
of intermediate points and then use the above formula.

In a general case, there can be problem concerning how to select the number
of points.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This is slightly different than what I want to do, I have the end of the lines specified. My overall goal here is to create equidistant points along the exterior of an irregular polygon.